# custom element without shadow DOM polymer 2.0

Tags: polymer-2.x

I am trying to create custom element without shadow DOM using polymer 2.0 with the below sample code from the https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/start/first-element/step-2

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="../iron-icon/iron-icon.html">
<dom-module id="icon-toggle">
  <template>
    <style>
      /* shadow DOM styles go here */
      :host {
        display: inline-block;
      }
      iron-icon {
        fill: rgba(0,0,0,0);
        stroke: currentcolor;
      }
      :host([pressed]) iron-icon {
        fill: currentcolor;
      }
    </style>
    <!-- shadow DOM goes here -->
    <iron-icon icon="polymer"></iron-icon>
  </template>
  <script>
    class IconToggle extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() {
      return "icon-toggle";
      }
      constructor() {
        super();
      }
    }
    customElements.define(IconToggle.is, IconToggle);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Could you please let me know whether it is possible with Polymer 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

In Polymer2, Custom Elements are created using 'Shadow-dom' by default. If you want to create one without shadow-dom, you can force shadyDom instead. Just add 'shadydom' as an attribute to you web components script call.

```
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js" shadydom></script>
```

Please note you will lose encapsulation with Shady Dom.

Comment: I wonder how this works for browsers like Chrome that don't rely on any polyfill. Will this force Chrome to use the Polyfill instead of its native Shadow DOM? If so, would this then negatively impact performance? (Which I guess you'd gain in other browsers)

Comment: @Hendrik you are right. Adding shadydom as an attribute to the script enforces polyfills in all browsers. Yes, I believe it will lose the benefits of shadow DOM and will hit the performance badly. I don't see any use cases to force shadydom though (except for testing purposes)

Comment: Thanks @Srikanth! I agree this isn't a viable option for most scenarios. It might open up some opportunities for a specific use case I am working on though....

Answer (score -1):

What are you trying?

- "I am trying to create custom element without polymer 2.0"

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements

- Could you please let me know whether it is possible with Polymer 2.0?

now im confused? So you want use Polymer or you wont use it?

Comment: sorry for the typo error ..I meant as per the heading ..without shadow DOM using Polymer 2.0

Comment: then just remove the template section

Comment: I am looking to use polymer2.0, if I remove template , it will be plain ES6 webcomponents